# How to extract a part of the web page source using Selenium and webdriver?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract a part of the web page source. Now I can extract all html code and output proper code. However, I want to extract only a part of code.

The following is their html code, I want to crawl. I want to crawl only red range:

[image]

And then, the following is my python code:

```
    from datetime import date,datetime
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    import numpy as np
    import xlrd
    import csv
    import codecs
    import time
    import os

        driver_blank=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
        driver_blank.get('https://forumd.hkgolden.com/view.aspx?type=CA&message=7223327')
        time.sleep(1)
        try_value = 1
        while(try_value):
            try:
                driver_blank.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/table[2]')
                print('OK')
                try_value=0
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                print('Refreash now')
                driver_blank.refresh()
                time.sleep(10)
        html_code = driver_blank.page_source
        print(html_code)
```

Can I use full Xpath to locate this range?

Comment: Why don't you use the class to get the grid ?

Comment: It is because I need to crawl a lot of same class name in the same page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want get the grid html You need to identify the `grid element` first and then use 
`get_attribute("outerHTML")`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

**Code**:

```
driver.get("https://forumd.hkgolden.com/view.aspx?type=CA&message=7223327")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//div[@class='ContentGrid'])[1]")))
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='ContentGrid'])[1]").get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

You need to add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: outerHtml contains also the grid tags. innerHTML is not an official DOM attribute, but supported by most browsers and returns only the content of the element.

Comment: @Justlearnedit : correct.I guess OP wants html not the content inside the tag.

Comment: Actually, I must use the full xpath. I changed to full path still success to crawl the information. Thank you~~~